# Syntax error in intent.putExtra(...)

Tags: android, eclipse-juno

[image]I'm following the dev guide at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html. I wrote the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

At the last line, I see a syntax error at `=intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)`. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Could you include the exact error message you're getting in your question?

Comment: Also include value of EXTRA_MESSAGE

Answer (score 1):

You can use in this way:-

```
intent.putExtra=("Extra_Message",message);
```

& Access the value of message On another activity from this:-

```
String message=getIntent().getExtra().getString("Extra_Message");
```

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with the actual question...?

Comment: Considering that Jaideep refuses to share the value of EXTRA_MESSAGE, this is the best suggestion I see as of now.

Comment: on ur (OnCreate) method in 2nd activity

Comment: STILL NOT GETTING PLEASE SEE ..THE GOOGLE DEV LINK AND WHAT WAS SHOWEN I DID BUT WHY IT IS STILL WRONG

Answer (score 1):

With intents, it's recommended ([if not required](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)) to use fully qualified names (package prefixed).  Simple string keys are more commonly associated with Bundles.

```
// Intent
intent.putExtra("com.my.example.EXTRA_IDENTIFIER", myValue);

// Bundle
bundle.putExtra("FavFruit", mApple);
```

Oh, and...

**It's impossible to diagnose your problem without the stack trace of the error from the LogCat.**

Comment: but in developers website what was showen i did same it is the google wrong...please help

Comment: another iam little stupid begginer and dont know how to use logcat please...help whenever i try it says of many filters -log tag-log message-PID please tell me how to use logcat ..i am preety intersted in android ..HELP

Comment: [The developer website is pretty clear how to use the logcat.](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) If you're not command-line inclined, you can try [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)

Comment: but i still dont understand please tell me how to!!

Comment: What don't you understand? BE SPECIFIC!

Comment: HOW TO FILTER ..WHAT PID AND THE FILTER OPTIONS I DONT UNDERSTAND

Comment: If you want to get into a screaming match...  You don't *need* to filter. From the screenshot it looks like it's not even "crashing" but throwing a compiler error. How much do you know about Java and using Eclipse?  Edit your post, add in *all the relevant* code, and *what line* the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a step where you define the value for EXTRA_MESSAGE.

Assign the text to a local message variable, and use the putExtra() method to add its text value to the intent.

**java/com.mycompany.myfirstapp/MyActivity.java**

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
  String message = editText.getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
```

An Intent can carry data types as key-value pairs called extras. The putExtra() method takes the key name in the first parameter and the value in the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an intent in the class body. It is not possible.

You have to create the intent and start the activity in a method.

First, define the `EXTRA_MESSAGE` at the top if its not defined :

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

Then edit your sendMessage method like this

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
  String message = editText.getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
```

And remove the code after closing bracket.